# How to define a deque (double sided queue) with a type struct?

Tags: c++

I am currently getting an error

```
"error: 'deque' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"
```

In my header file, I have a `struct testStruct` that I define as such:

```
struct testStruct{ /*vars*/ };
```

at the bottom of the header file, I declare a `deque` as such:

```
extern std::deque<testStruct> *testQueue;
```

I did not declare that I am `using namespace std` and I have have the `queue.h` library included. Even when I replace the type to something simple like `int` it gives the same error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include `deque`, not `queue.h` to use `std::deque`.

This [website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) lists several components that can be used within the standard library. It also shows in which header each component can be found.

Comment: Its giving me a fatal error when I do #include <deque.h>. It says no such file or directory. Am I not including it properly? I'm guessing its not in the the current libraries I have available to me.

Comment: Try <deque> not <deque.h>